# How to use Gnome/Ubuntu media key binding in other window environments?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xmonad

I had an older laptop with ubuntu 13.04 (upgraded a few times) where I've installed xmonad. In xmonad I would get all the media keys bindings from ubuntu (including osd notifications). I'm not sure what it was, but perhaps it was `gnome-settings-daemon` that was taking care of it because there are entries in dconf for that.

In my new laptop I installed Xfce through a minimal iso, then compiled Xmonad. I tried to keep the same environment -- `gnome-settings-daemon` is run in `.xinitrc` as before and gsettings contains the same bindings. However, the key bindings do not work. What am I missing? I guess I could try to install the whole `ubuntu-desktop` but I have a small SSD so I'd like to avoid that.

I know Xmonad can define its own custom handlers, but I'm having trouble with defining volume control actions and I figured it would be easier to just use what's out there already.

tl;dr

What executables/packages/config entries are necessary to get ubuntu/gnome keybindings work in another window manager? Can I get them to work without pulling in the whole `ubuntu-desktop`? I am running `gnome-settings-daemon` + the media-keys plugin is active in dconf, but the keys are not handled.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like GNOME removed the media key handling from gnome-settings-daemon and integrated it into gnome-shell:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1262789

I'm still looking for a good solution. Arch/Cinnamon people have apparently forked the 3.6 version.

Comment: Any news on this? This is still broken and there is no way to fix this on ubuntu without using unity??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dconf instead of xmonad controls, you should disable xmonad plugin (since it could cause interference) and then go down to the following path using the `dconf-editor`:

```
 org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
```

Here there are all the keys you need to configure your media actions. You should mark it as `active` in the first key so it works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's not an answer to my question. I know how to bind keys in xmonad, and I know how to edit gconf/dconf stuff. To be specific, Xmonad-extras has a volume module that seems to have a bug -- toggleMuting is able to mute the audio but does not restore it. That's why I was trying to get ubuntu/gnome to handle the media keys like on my previous laptop.

Comment: @BruceBerry can you rephrase the question then and specify what you don't know? As I know what keys should be modified to make dconf use the volumes.

Comment: I don't know why ubuntu/gnome keys bindings are not active in my Xsession-Xmonad despite having them in dconf and running `gnome-settings-daemon`. I guess I am missing some other package from `ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: @BruceBerry ok, but please, edit your question and include that, since the 3 paragraphs are just about xmonad. Also I believe that right now it should answer your question.

Comment: my problem is that despite these conf entries being there already, it still doesn't work. I've updated the question with a final paragraph.

Comment: @BruceBerry you sure the first key is set to true? Check the last image. Also a logout may be required.

Comment: i'm positive. btw, i also run `gnome-settings-daemon` in debug mode and when pressing the media keys no message was displayed.

Comment: Mmm... then something is definitively wrong. Try with other user then.